# Firefox signin issue: Signin with Google option is not available

Tags: firefox, google-signin

I signed in with google to firefox account.
But now there is no option for it. If I reset my password then I will lose all my synced data.

How can I sign in using google so that I would not lose my data?

Answer (score 0):

You can export bookmark from Firefox browser with HTML type and save it.
and import to another browser , for example chrome .
In the Firefox , go to :  menu > bookmarks > manage bookmarks and top of page , Import and backup and export bookmarks to HTML.
For Example , for import to chrome , go to : menu > bookmarks > import bookmarks and setting and select HTML file for import.